# Rack::Deflater and gzip in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gzip, rack, deflate

I added `use Rack::Deflater` to config.ru in an attempt to serve gzipped css and js.

but when I load the page I still see that css and js are served and not the css.gz

should I see css.gz or js.gz? or did I miss something

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the correct behavior. Check your HTTP headers to see if the gzip compression actually works:

```
curl -I -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" <url>
```

This should return something like `Content-Encoding: gzip` if gzip compression is enabled.

You can also see the compressed output by using a lowercase `-i`. Alternatively to curl, you can also use the WebKit developer tools (or something similiar) to check this.